# Matching a number against a comma-separated sequence of ranges

Tags: bash, shell, range

I'm writing a bash script which takes a number, and also a comma-separated sequence of values and strings, e.g.: `3,15,4-7,19-20`. I want to check whether the number is contained in the set corresponding to the sequence. For simplicity, assume no comma-separated elements intersect, and that the elements are sorted in ascending order.

Is there a simple way to do this in bash other than the brute-force naive way? Some shell utility which does something like that for me, maybe something related to lpr which already knows how to process page range sequences etc.

Comment: Brute force would be to test your number against every range in the list until you find a match?

Comment: @Fravadona: Yes. I was hoping the was some shell utility which does something like that for me, maybe something related to lpr which already knows how to process page range sequences etc.

Comment: So "the set corresponding to the sequence" includes interpreting the hyphen-separated pairs as ranges?

Comment: I don't know of any bash builtin that could do that, and using an external utility may be slower that writing it with pure bash

Comment: And I don't know any external utility providing such evaluation.  A few command-line tools do consume such range specifications, but that doesn't make their internal mechanisms for evaluating those ranges accessible from Bash.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes

Comment: Will you be testing a lot of numbers against the same range list? If so then what would you like to have as a _global_ result for testing a few numbers at the same time?

Comment: @Fravadona : I may, or I may not... but if I do - then I guess an array of 0/1's.

Answer (score 2):

Is awk cheating?:

```
$ echo -n 3,15,4-7,19-20 | 
  awk -v val=6 -v RS=, -F- '(NF==1&&$1==val) || (NF==2&&$1<=val&&$2>=val)' -
```

Output:

```
4-7
```

Another version:

```
$ echo 19 |
awk -v ranges=3,15,4-7,19-20 '
BEGIN {
    split(ranges,a,/,/)
}
{
    for(i in a) {
        n=split(a[i],b,/-/)
        if((n==1 && $1==a[i]) || (n==2 && $1>=b[1] && $1<=b[2]))
            print a[i]
    }
}' -
```

Outputs:

```
19-20
```

The latter is better as you can feed it more values from a file etc. Then again the former is shorter. :D

Comment: Can you rewrite this to take val as a first argument and the sequence of ranges as the second one?

Comment: I don't know whether that counts as "brute force", but it seems unlikely that there is anything much simpler.

Comment: Sure, it'll be a bit longer, tho, but much more understandable.

Comment: @JamesBrown: So maybe add it after the first version?

Comment: Redirecting from a here string could move the range from the front of the pipeline to elsewhere in the command.  Wrapping that up in a shell function would allow the redirection to be concealed and the arguments (to the function) to be presented in whatever order the function's author prefers.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Already posted that as an answer.

Comment: Possibility for ranges such as `21-` or `-2` left as  an exercise...

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash:

```sh
check() {
  IFS=, a=($2)
  for b in "${a[@]}"; do
    IFS=- c=($b); c+=(${c[0]})
    (( $1 >= c[0] && $1 <= c[1] )) && break
  done
}

$ check 6 '3,15,4-7,19-20' && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
$ check 42 '3,15,4-7,19-20' && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Comment: Do you believe this is preferable to using the awk solution?

Comment: I don't know. You asked for a bash solution, so this is one. If there are possibilities that `awk` is not available, or you have an `awk` version that does not support a given feature it may be better to stick to bash. On the performance point of view it could be that they are about the same for just one run. But if you want to call the bash function many times in a row, it will probably be slower than a **single** `awk` run that would process all inputs.

Comment: this solution is cunning and above all the global IFS isn't modified +1

Comment: I never modify `IFS` globally. [Greg](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) would be mad at me ;-).

Answer (score 1):

As `bash` is tagged, why not just

```sh
inrange() { for r in ${2//,/ }; do ((${r%-*}<=$1 && $1<=${r#*-})) && break; done; }
```

Then test it as usual:

```sh
$ inrange 6 3,15,4-7,19-20 && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ inrange 42 3,15,4-7,19-20 && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Answer (score 0):

A function based on @JamesBrown's method:

```
function match_in_range_seq {
    (( $# == 2 )) && [[ -n "$(echo -n "$2" | awk -v val="$1" -v RS=, -F- '(NF==1&&$1==val) || (NF==2&&$1<=val&&$2>=val)' - )" ]]
}
```

Will return 0 (in `$?`) if the second argument (the range sequence) contains the first argument, 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` idea using two input (`-v`) variables:

```
# use of function wrapper is optional but cleaner for the follow-on test run

in_range() {

awk -v value="$1" -v r="$2" '
BEGIN { n=split(r,ranges,",")
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            low=high=ranges[i]
            if (ranges[i] ~ "-") {
               split(ranges[i],x,"-")
               low=x[1]
               high=x[2]
            }
            if (value >= low && value <= high) {
               print value,"found in the range:",ranges[i]
               exit
            }
        }
      }'
}
```

**NOTE:** the `exit` assumes no overlapping ranges, ie, `value` will not be found in more than one 'range'

Take for a test spin:

```
ranges='3,15,4-7,19-20'

for value in 1 6 15 32
do
    echo "########### value = ${value}"
    in_range "${value}" "${ranges}"
done
```

This generates:

```
########### value = 1
########### value = 6
6 found in the range: 4-7
########### value = 15
15 found in the range: 15
########### value = 32
```

**NOTES:**

- OP did not mention what to generate as output if no range match is found; code could be modified to output a 'not found' message as needed
- in a comment OP mentioned possibly running the search for a number of `value`s; code could be modified to support such a requirement but would need more input (eg, format of list of `value`s, desired output and how to be used/captured by calling process, etc)